# Simple form: how to set values of a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have the following code below:

```
= simple_form_for :credits, url: "/accounts/#{@account.id}/topup" do |f|
  = f.input :amount, collection: [100,500,1000,5000,10000],as: :radio_buttons
  = f.button :submit
```

It works to set all values and labels in the collection. What I want is something like,

```
label: 100, value: 500
```

How would that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this (from the [simpleform github](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collection-check-boxes)).

Their example is:

```
form_for @user do |f|
  f.collection_check_boxes :options, [[true, 'Yes'] ,[false, 'No']], :first, :last
end
```

and

so i think yours should looks something like:

```
= simple_form_for :credits, url: "/accounts/#{@account.id}/topup" do |f|
  = f.collection_check_boxes :amount, [[100, 500], [500, 'a'], [1000, 'b'], [5000, 'c'], [10000, 'd']]
= f.button :submit
```

Comment: Added :first, :last in the end then worked like a charm. Thanks! Thanks to everyone as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an array of arrays:

```
[[100, "One Hundred"], [200, "Two Hundred"], [300, "SPARTA!"]]
```

You can then set the value and label separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked for me:

```
= simple_form_for :credits, url: "/accounts/#{@account.id}/topup" do |f|
  = f.input :amount, collection: [['100','500'], ['1000','5000'] ,['10000', '23']], as: :radio_buttons
  = f.button :submit
```